# How can I paste full path strings in the GNOME File Selection Dialog on RHEL?

Tags: rhel, filenames, gui, gtk, dialog

I have a remote RHEL machine which I use via X11. On that machine when I open a new file in, say, VS Code or in the Firefox browser (both apps are on teh remote machine), then I get teh following File Selection Dialog:

[image: File Selection Dialog]

In this Dialog I get only to teh desired loaction by mutiple clicks on teh various path elements. However very often I have a path string like `/opt/servers/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/conf/server.xml` in the clipboard which I just could paste to get to the desired location.

Are File Selection Dialogs available which can use a full path string and how do I hook them up to the RHEL system?

#### Some more details:

| Info | Value |
| --- | --- |
| **Remote OS:** | Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 |
| **Local X11 "server":** | MobaXterm on Windows |

Comment: Does `Ctrl + L` work?

Comment: YES! You are my hero! Not the solution I was thinking of, yet much simpler! Thanks heaps. If you make it into answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Glad this worked for you :) ! Added answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the file managers have the feature to *type/autocomplete paths* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

And it seems to be working both `GTK` and `QT` based applications. I tested in KDE and GNOME as well and both work. But not really sure if there are `Open/Save File Dialogs` whose don't have that feature.