# How to make File explorer Address Bar path editable in Linux Mint or in Zorin or in any Debian based OS?

Tags: file-manager, zorin

I am using `Zorin OS`. Consider the below screenshot:

[image]

I want the **Address Bar** editable to write the path of my intended folder location.

Are there any settings that need to be configured or is there any software required to install?

Comment: This might be useful: [How can I paste full path strings in the GNOME File Selection Dialog on RHEL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727469/414186)

Comment: The default file manager of Zorin OS is Nautilus, and what you're looking for is not possible. According to https://keycombiner.com/collections/nautilus/ you can press 'CTRL'+'L' to open a location bar, where you can directly type the location you want to open. If you want an functionality akin to a web browser, you need to search for a file manager that has an editable address bar.

Comment: @Peregrino69 That is Exactly what I wanted for. Thank You. `CTRL + L`

Comment: Excellent! Do feel free to make it an answer and accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Dolphin File Manager is the default file manager in KDE Plasma desktop and allows you to set the address bar to an editable address bar. Dolphin checks all the boxes when it comes to the features I want in a file manager.

You can install dolphin in Linux Mint
[https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=11211#:~:text=Go%20to%20your%20home%20folder,of%20file%22%20and%20click%20ok](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=11211#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20your%20home%20folder,of%20file%22%20and%20click%20ok).